# Str.Slice Slicing Spaces

Tags: javascript, string, slice

This is my typing game code. Feel free to test it if needed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onkeypress="myFunction(event)">
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            p::first-letter {
            background-color: blue;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script scr="script.js">
        //base value for correct letters typed
        var z = 0
        //chooses random sentence (changable)
        var myArray = [
            "Repl.it is the best website in the world",
            "Nothing can bet Repl.it in code editors",
            "I hope the developers will give me hacker plan for complimenting Repl.it",
            "Post your sentence suggestions below because I am horrible at creating sentences",
            "I have been on Repl.it for 2 months",
        ];
        var str = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
        //replaces ('demo') with random sentence

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;

        var a = str.length
        var n = str.charAt(z)
        console.log(a)
        var x = null
        var y = null
        function myFunction(event) {
            //find key pressed
            x = event.keyCode;
            y = String.fromCharCode(x);
            myFunction2() //see below
        }

        function myFunction2() {
            if (y == n) { //check if correct key
                z = z + 1;
                n = str.charAt(z)
                console.log(n)
                test()
                document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "black";

            } else { //if not correct key change to red
                 document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
            }

        }
        function test() {
                if (z == a) {
                    document.write("END")
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str.slice(z)
                }

        }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The str.slice is slicing off the spaces. 
Is there any way to not slice the space?
or is there any other function which does it? 
Which still leaves a space? (I couldn't find one online)

Thanks in advance,
 Matthew

Comment: Why not update the `str` variable with each key input, or use another variable to keep track of changes to the on-screen text? By updating the variable on each keypress, it's easier to manage what you want user to type next e.g.: `str = str.trimLeft()` to remove the spaces

Comment: If you want to keep `str` constant though, you could try this instead: `str.replace(' ', "").slice(z)`. Also recommend `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` when working with strings that don't contain HTML code.